# Java interface generic type

Tags: java, generics, interface

Never used Java before and trying to implement an interface in a class:

Interface:

```
public interface TestInterface<E> {
        public void doSomething(E elem);
}
```

Class:

```
public class TestClass implements TestInterface<E> {
    public static void main() {
        // ...
    }
    public void doSomething(E elem) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When I run the javac compiler. I get these errors:

```
TestClass.java:5: cannot find symbol
symbol: class E
      public class TestClass implements TestInterface<E> {
                                                      ^
TestClass.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class E
location: class TestClass
      public void doSomething(E elem) {
                              ^
```

If I replace all the "E"'s with i.e. "String", it will work, but I want it to use generic types. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating `TestClass` you need to pass what is `E`,  something like below

```
public class TestClass implements TestInterface<String> {
    public static void main() {
        // ...

    }
    public void doSomething(String elem) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

or you need to make `TestClass` as generic

```
public class TestClass<E> implements TestInterface<E> {
     public static void main() {
            // ...

     }
     public void doSomething(E elem) {
            // ...
     }
}
```

Comment: ahh, that's it, just the <E> after the class name did it. Thanks!